# How to use jekyll on an existing blog made with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, github-pages

My situation is that I have just finished creating a blog using ruby on rails. I have been using localhost to see it display on my browser, but I want to deploy it online. I found out that rails apps can't be deployed on ghpages because it is not static. However, I searched online and read that if I used Jekyll, i could display it on ghpages. I have never used jekyll before, so my question is...

How could I use/integrate jekyll to my existing rails app so that it can be deployed and hosted through github pages?

Thank you!

Comment: jekyll is a static site generator, while  rails is mostly used for developing web apps that heavily rely on dynamic data. It would be difficult to say anything before the nature of your site is known. How much of your site is based on dynamic data provided by dbms?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to screw in a screw with a hammer.

Github pages is simple free hosting for static pages like a simple portfolio or the info page for a github project. You would use jekyll to generate simple static HTML pages for this.

If you want to deploy a Rails application there are several cloud hosting providers such as [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/?sc_cid=701600000011p9xAAA&gclid=CjwKEAiAmo_CBRC9qbGQssjqi28SJABYTgZx4e404e9xpf9vrmQN2PGoYgE7Rye9OwA9FT-nNv9m3RoCsT3w_wcB) that provide a free tier.

First determine what you are trying to build. Then select the right tool and hosting for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You **CANNOT** host a rails blog app with databases on gh pages. you need a static site to be hosted on ghpages. jekyll is a static site generator that generates static HTML pages which can be served to users from gh-pages.

So you need to build new blog engine with jekyll

- install jekyll: `gem install jekyll`
- create new jekyll site: `jekyll new your-github-username.github.io`
- cd to the new directory generated and test locally: `jekyll serve` (visit http://localhost:4000)

[link to github articles on gh-pages with jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/)